# CanCan::AccessDenied with factory_girl and cancan, How correctly to write the factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise, factory-bot, cancan

I am suffering for the third day, I can not understand why I do not pass the next test:

```
 4) Error:
ArticlesControllerTest#test_should_get_index_if_admin:
CanCan::AccessDenied: You are not authorized to access this page.
    test/controllers/articles_controller_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:ArticlesControllerTest>'
```

What am I doing wrong? help me please!

I have got old application (rails 4.2), with many fixtures data.

I try migrate my test environment from fixtures to factory_girl. So I'm new to this.

Now I'm using:

- cancancan + devise
- factory_girl + TestCase

My articles controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).includes(:translations)
  end
end
```

Ability.rb:

```
Class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability

 def initialize(user)
   user ||= User.new

   # Everybody
   can :show, [Article]

   if user.admin?
     can :manage, Article
   end
 end
end
```

My factory article.rb is very simple:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :article do
   content "MyText"

   factory :one_article
   factory :two_article
 end
end
```

My factory user.rb is simple too:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@mail.ru" }
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    after(:create) {|u| u.roles_mask = 4}
    profile

    factory :valid_admin do
      first_name "Administrator"
      last_name "Administrator"
      association :profile, factory: :admin_profile
      after(:create) {|u| u.roles_mask = 2}
    end
  end
end
```

My articles controller test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ArticlesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

  setup do
    @article = create(:one_article)
    @admin   = create(:valid_admin)
  end

  test 'should get index if admin' do
    sign_in @admin

    ability = Ability.new(@admin)
    assert ability.can? :index, Article

    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:articles)
  end
end
```

Info by pry:

```
[1] pry(#<ArticlesControllerTest>)> sign_in @admin
=> [[20709], "9BET5RWNuJPrGHUFi86d"]
[2] pry(#<ArticlesControllerTest>)> ability = Ability.new(@admin)
=> #<Ability:0x0000000c3c5ff8
 @rules=
  [#<CanCan::Rule:0x0000000c3c5f80
    @actions=[:show],
    @base_behavior=true,
    @block=nil,
.............<<Many lines>> ..............
[3] pry(#<ArticlesControllerTest>)> assert ability.can? :index, Article
=> true
[4] pry(#<ArticlesControllerTest>)> get :index
CanCan::AccessDenied: You are not authorized to access this page.
from /home/da/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6@wenya/gems/cancancan-1.16.0/lib/cancan/ability.rb:217:in `authorize!'
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If this is a new app use ` ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` instead of a controller test. Also I would use a separate test to test your ability class in isolation instead of doing it here.

Comment: I also really don't get what you're trying to do with the factory. I usually use FactoryGirl with  ffaker to generate random data. Defining factories like `factory :one_article` smells like a fixture. Factories are not fixtures. They are factories that should create unique items. If you are hardcoding the values of your factories into your specs you're doing it wrong. Bad : `expect(page).to have_link("Foo")` Good:   `expect(page).to have_link(article.name)`

Comment: I really did not understand the principle of testing with the help of a cup, now I have become more advanced in this matter) thanks for your tip-off! I removed the extra garbage, remade some entities in trait, and these errors disappeared!

Answer (score 1):

This are the devise guideline, you need to create a method to log in the user as admin. This is the [login_method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29#controller-tests-testunit) you need to create

> Controller tests (Test::Unit)
>
> To sign in as admin for a given test case, just do:

```
class SomeControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  # For Devise >= 4.1.1
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
  # Use the following instead if you are on Devise <= 4.1.0
  # include Devise::TestHelpers

  def setup
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
    sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
  end
end
```

> Note: If you are using the confirmable module, you should set a confirmed_at date inside the Factory or call confirm! before sign_in.
>
> Here is the basics to prepare inside your Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    confirmed_at Date.today
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: @Sean Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't use rspec

Comment: @nilid hello, does this solve your question? I updated my answer. you can check devise documentation for more info about testing

Comment: I always use `Faker::Internet.safe_email` which gives `@example.com` adresses just in case I really screw up and actually send emails. I'm probaly just paranoid though.

Comment: @max you will not send email in development or test environment. The server is going to show you a test email in the log. You can click the link in your server log to confirm the email. To enable the email sending you need to do setting in your `production.rb` file, so this should not cause the sending of email. Also I believe there is worst things to worry for, anyway way are you thinking about this?

Comment: Its actually `test.rb` and I have seen it happen (but not in Rails).